# How to correctly represent a "warehouse" in django - n+1 problems

Tags: python, django, select-n-plus-1

I'm learning Django.
I am trying to make an app for managin a warehouse that's composed by simple elements:

Involved models are transaction, items, warehouses and homes.

`models.py`:

```
class Home(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('name'),blank=False)

class Warehouse(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('name'),blank=False)

class Item(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('name'),
    whouse = models.ForeignKey('Warehouse', blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='all_items')
    quantity    = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name=_('Quantity'), default=1, blank=False)
    @cached_property
    def count_remaining(self):
        remaining = self.quantity
        qs = self.transactions.all()
        if qs:
            out = qs.aggregate(Sum('quantity'))['quantity__sum']
            if out:
                remaining -= out
        return remaining


class Transaction(Model):
    item_field = models.ForeignKey('Item', blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='all_transactions')
    home_field = models.ForeignKey('Home', blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='all_transactions')
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name=_('Quantity'), default=1, blank=False)
```

`item_list.html` (for the generic ListView, with `qs=Item.objects.all()`):

```
...
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>quantity</td>
        <td>remaining items</td>
        <td>whouse</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in item_list %}
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.count_remaining }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.whouse }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
...
```

Now my problem is that my `count_remaining` method is being called one time for each object in the queryset, obviously resulting in an exponential number of database hits when there are many items in item_list.

How can I make this arithmetical operation without hitting the db so much, provided that I must have a page that displays in the template the remaining items in the warehouse?

Comment: You could just use the quantity attribute in Item class. Every time a transaction is made, call a method in Item class that reduces the quantity by the number of purchased items.

Comment: I went for this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists()` instead `all()`:

```
@cached_property
def count_remaining(self):
    remaining = self.quantity
    # related_name='all_transactions'
    qs = self.all_transactions
    if qs.exists():
        out = qs.aggregate(Sum('quantity'))['quantity__sum']
        remaining -= out
    return remaining
```

See [django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists)

Comment: This will not reduce the number of queries, as the qs is still made by self.transaction.all(), making a call to the database

Comment: @Kodeeo, to reduce the number of queries, you can directly do `self.transaction.aggregate(Sum('quantity'))['quantity__sum']`. Without checking for transactions: If no transactions, it will be anyway **0**.

Comment: Sure but doing the sum will hit DB anyway